# How to start an Activity on clicking the Search button on an Android handset

Tags: android, search

I would like to start `MyActivity` class when the user clicks on the search button on the handset.

Are there any strategies you can suggest for this? Any code examples would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two places you can consider:

- in an activity, you should implement `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`, and check `keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH`
- from the home screen (from Android 1.6 on), you can use the [SearchManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#ExposingSearchSuggestionsToQuickSearchBox) to extend the Quick Search Box.
- from the home screen (for Android 1.5), there is a `searchable.xml` API which can be exposed by using an `android.intent.action.SEARCH` intent-filter. This is forwards compatible, so is probably better if you are constrained to this version of the API. There is a [compare/contrast document](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html).

This is probably not what you're looking for directly, but I think should help solve the problem you're trying to solve.